# ray setting the working directory via runtime environment

Tags: python, ray

Suppose I'm trying to import a module located here "/home/target_module/module.py" and suppose I'm launching ray from a script located here "/home/another_module/main.py".

The docs (https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/ray-core/handling-dependencies.html) state to set the working directory appropriately to import the desired module when launching ray. What value should I set the working_dir to (see https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/ray-core/api/doc/ray.runtime_env.RuntimeEnv.html#ray.runtime_env.RuntimeEnv) to successfully import? I've tried "/home" but that causes ray.init() to hang.